# Agreggate functions in marklogic-client-api

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Is it possible to do grouping queries and aggregate results by using marklogic-client-api? For example, I have 3 indexes for an entity and want to group the results by them and know the 'count' for each triple.

Supposing it is possible to do something like, would it be possible to do the same using data data movement api?

I know there is `cts:element-value-co-occurrences`, but I don't think I can use it in marklogic-client-api.

Comment: Are you referring to the Java Client API, the Node Client API, or the REST Client API?

Comment: I'm referring to java client api, more specifically to this: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>marklogic-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Optic API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/OpticJava#chapter), which can be used from Java, Node.js, and REST as well as JavaScript and XQuery. With Optic, you can [groupBy](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/expression/PlanBuilder.ModifyPlan.html#groupBy-com.marklogic.client.type.PlanExprColSeq-) and [calculate aggregates](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_23596).

Comment: thanks, it looks promising! I'll try that soon (probably only from monday on) and report back.

Comment: I'm looking the Optic API and something is not clear for me: what is a field? A column is something that must have a range index, but I don't see any good description for a field. Maybe it is http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields ? Also, what if I want to return something that isn't a range index (otherwise I may end adding range indexes for all attributes in my objects)?